# TypeError: Series.cov() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, yfinance

Get an TypeError when compiling this code:

TypeError: Series.cov() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'

. What is my problem?

```
def portifolioOptimalization(inputStocks):
    
    stocks = inputStocks

    portifolioData = yf.download(stocks, '2020-1-1')['Close']

    portifolioReturns = portifolioData.pct_change()
    numberOfStocks = len(inputStocks)
    portifolioWeight = []
    
    global weightSum
    weightSum = 1

    for i in range(0,numberOfStocks-1):

        stockWeight = round(random.uniform(0.0, weightSum), 2)

        weightSum = weightSum - stockWeight

        portifolioWeight.append(stockWeight)
    
    portifolioWeight.append(weightSum)
    portifolioReturns = portifolioReturns.dot(portifolioWeight)
    

    varianceMatrix = portifolioReturns.cov()
```

Expects a covariance matrix

Comment: You forgot to look at the docs for `cov`.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cov.html